# Angular UI Bootstrap Modal update $scope

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to use the modal to edit my data. I pass the data to the modal instance. When I click ok I pass the edited data in the $scope.selected back to the controller.

There I would like to update the original $scope. Somehow the $scope doesn't update though. What am I doing wrong?

```
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

  $scope.data = { name: '', serial: ''  }

  $scope.edit = function (theIndex) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.data[theIndex];
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;

      // this is where the data gets updated, but doesn't do it
      $scope.data.name = $scope.selected.name;
      $scope.data.serial = $scope.selected.serial;

    });
  };
};
```

Modal Controller:

```
var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
    name: $scope.items.name,
    serial: $scope.items.serial
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
};
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3>{{ name }}</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <input type="text" value="{{ serial }}">
    <input type="text" value="{{ name }}">
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hehe thx ye little typo, but doesn't solve the problem :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You didn't include your template for the modal, so this is a bit of a guess. Your code is pretty close to the example code for the angular-ui modal, which uses `ng-repeat` in the template. If you're doing the same thing, then you should be aware that `ng-repeat` creates a child scope which inherits from the parent.

Judging from this snippet:

```
$scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected);
};
```

it looks like instead of doing this in your template:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
    <a ng-click="selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
</li>
```

you may be doing something like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
    <a ng-click="selected = item">{{ item }}</a>
</li>
```

If so, then in your case, you're assigning `selected` in the child scope, and this will not affect the parent scope's `selected` property. Then, when you try to access `$scope.selected.name`, it will be empty.
In general, you should use objects for your models, and set properties on them, not assign new values directly.

[This part of the documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) explains the scope problem in more detail.

Edit:

You are also not binding your inputs to any model at all, so the data you enter there is never stored anywhere. You need to use `ng-model` to do that, e.g.:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="editable.serial" />
<input type="text" ng-model="editable.name" />
```

See [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/WtjYirZo9wKBctGomV4w) for a working example.

Comment: thx I'm just using two inputs to update "name" and "serial". No ng-repeat